# how run with \Arachnid\Crawler in URL with CURL

Tags: php, curl, cron

i use that:
https://github.com/zrashwani/arachnid

and i do that:

```
$url = "www.google.com";
$crawler = new \Arachnid\Crawler($url, 2);
$crawler->traverse();
```

i run that with cron in php
and i have a URL that i can to come in to him with cron
that give me a blnk page
how i do with that apps a
how i add that code to my code:

```
$userAgent = "IE 7 – Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30)";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
```

Comment: You expect the community to help you with your problem and you can't even spare a few seconds more editing your question to be more readable. (Capital letters at the sentence start, dots at the end etc.)

Comment: sorry about my english
i have a url that i can to run with cron PHP but i can come in to the URL with my brower